# Stochastic exercise with exponential distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution

I have a little problem with this exercise.

The lifetime of a device (in years) is exponentially distributed with the parameter $λ = 0.02$.

After what time are 25% of all devices that were produced at time $t = 0$ still functional?

I have done what follows:

Let $g$ be $=0$ if the device is not functional and $=1$ if it is functional.

Now we must find $t$ so that $P(g=1)=0.25$

So we have
$=0.02e^{-0.02t}=\frac{25}{100}$

so we have

$e^{-0.02t}=\frac{25}{2}$

$t=\frac{ln(\frac{25}{2})}{-0.02}$

But the result seems wrong. Where is my error?

Comment: I think that it depends on the number of devices,  which we don't know.

Comment: Die Originalaufgabe wäre sicher auch hilfreich.

Comment: Das ist die Originalaufgabe (aber auf Englisch uebersetzt)

Comment: Ich wollte eben mal die Originalaufgabe sehen. Auch bei deutschen Texten, die in Deutsch wiedergegeben werden, wird häufig unabsichtlich ein Detail weggelassen. Es ist natürlich nur ein Angebot.

Comment: Die Lebenszeit eines Gerätes (in Jahren) sei exponentialverteilt zum Parameter $λ = 0,02$.
Nach welcher Zeit sind $25 $% aller Geräte, die zum Zeitpunkt $t = 0$ produziert wurden, noch funktionstuchtig?

Comment: Danke. Ohne die Anzahl der Geräte macht die Aufgabe eigentlich keinen Sinn.